# Jumping multiple lines at once causes weird behaviour on screen

Tags: vim, tmux, nerdtree, konsole

In Vim, when trying to jump multiple lines at once (for example with `G` or `gg`) The on screen text does not get drawn correctly if I am jumping beyond what I can currently see on the screen.

The text from the old cursor position fills up the whitespace around the new location.

I tried redrawing the buffer with `<Esc>:redraw<CR>` to no avail.

My `.vimrc` is fairly simple and I don't think that should be causing the issue.

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
        Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
        Plugin 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'
        Plugin 'preservim/nerdtree'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin on

colorscheme nord
set relativenumber number
syntax on
set bs=2
set smartindent autoindent

nmap <silent> <F8> :call ToggleDiff()<CR>
function ToggleDiff()
        if(&diff)
                windo diffoff
        else
                windo diffthis
        endif
endfunction
```

I am using tmux on Konsole.

Here is `.tmux.conf`

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %
bind -n C-x select-pane -t :.+
bind-key -r -T prefix C-j resize-pane -D 5
bind-key -r -T prefix C-h resize-pane -L 5
bind-key -r -T prefix C-k resize-pane -U 5
bind-key -r -T prefix C-l resize-pane -R 5

# Design changes
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"

# Global options
set-option -g allow-rename off

# Nord options
set -g @nord_tmux_no_patched_font "1"

# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin "arcticicestudio/nord-tmux"

run -b '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

Also I am using the system remotely through etx, although I have been using that since a long time and that did not cause any issues.

---

Edit:

Just observed. The issue does not occur when NERDTree is open on the side. This kind of makes sense as the issue popped up only when I added the NERDTree plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Does this still happen if you set `default-terminal` to `tmux-256color` or `screen-256color` and restart tmux (`tmux kill-server`)? Make sure `TERM` is `tmux-256color` or `screen-256color` inside tmux.

Also how old is your Konsole? This could be the `indn` bug in Konsole. Try this in `.tmux.conf` and restart tmux:

```
set -as terminal-overrides ',*:indn@'
```